# HTML Form JS Only Sent to Database IF email is not valid

Tags: javascript, firebase, forms

I'm stumped on HTML form working on why it is only send to the database if the email is NOT valid.  I would like it to only work IF the email is valid. If it's a valid email, it doesn't end up in the db. There must be something I'm missing.  I'm new to HTML and JS.  Any suggestions will help. Thank you

```
                <form class="contact-form">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="center-holder">
                        <button id="submit_msg" type="submit">Send Message</button>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- Form End -->
```

Here is JS file

```
    var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxx",
    authDomain: "https://xxxxx",
    databaseURL: "https:/xxxxx.firebaseio.com/",
    projectId: "xxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxx"
};
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    var push_to_firebase = function(data){
      var db = firebase.firestore();

      db.collection("messages").add({
          name: data["name"],
          email: data["email"],
          message: data["msg"],
          timestamp: Date.now()
      })
    }

    var contact_submit = function(){
      var name = document.getElementById("name");
      var email = document.getElementById("email");
      var msg = document.getElementById("message");

      var data = {
        "name": name.value,
        "email": email.value,
        "msg": msg.value
      }
      push_to_firebase(data);  
    }

    document.getElementById("submit_msg").addEventListener("click", contact_submit);
  })();
```

Comment: is there anything in the browser developer tools console/network tab to help you debug this?

Answer (score 0):

you can validate email first before saving in firebase

```
const validateEmail = (email) => {
  return String(email)
    .toLowerCase()
    .match(
      /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
    );
};

// run this function first, if it returns true then continue to save in database
```